# eslint complaining about spread operator in simple React reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

I've got a very simple React reducer and eslint is complaining about how I spread state. Below is the code. I expected that it would be OK. I'm pasting my .eslintrc below also.

```
function quizReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RESET_QUIZ:
      return {
        ...state,
        currentQuestion: 0,
        currentAnswer: '',
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

eslintrc

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "destructuring": true,
      "spread": true,
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
  },
  "plugins": ["react-hooks"],
  "rules": {
    //additional rules here
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error"
  }
}
```

The error is on the ...state line and is

```
ESLint: Parsing error: Unexpected token ...
```

Comment: "*complaining*"–Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that. I'll update the question (was busy tripping over formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to delete lines from eslintrc, after "jsx": true, you should get the following :

```
"parserOptions": {
  "ecmaVersion": 2020,
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true
  }
}
```

Comment: that didn't work but good hint.  I got rid of all by jsx as true and changed to "ecmaVersion": 2020, and that worked. Please updated your answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: glad that the tip worked, in my case it's work even with "ecmaVersion": 6

Answer (score 1):

In version 5.0.0 of ESLint, [the `experimentalObjectRestSpread` option was deprecated](https://eslint.org/docs/5.0.0/user-guide/migrating-to-5.0.0#the-experimentalobjectrestspread-option-has-been-deprecated).

Trying removing all the options from your `ecmaFeatures` except `jsx`. Also change your `ecmaVersion` to at least year `2018` or version `9` (or later), as described at that same link.

```js
    "ecmaVersion": 2018, // or 9
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
    }
```